# how to correctly subquery related models

Tags: go, go-gorm

I`m trying to figure out the right and elegant query.
There are three tables

```
type Project struct {
    ID           uuid.UUID `gorm:"type:uuid;primary_key;auto_increment:false"`
    Name         string
}
```

```
type Folder struct {
    ID                          uuid.UUID `gorm:"type:uuid;primary_key;auto_increment:false"`
    Name                        string
    ProjectID                   uuid.UUID `gorm:"type:uuid;index"`
}
```

```
type Model struct {
    ID                             uuid.UUID `gorm:"type:uuid;primary_key;auto_increment:false"`
    Name                           string
    ParentModelID                  uuid.UUID `gorm:"type:uuid;index"`
    FolderID                       uuid.UUID `gorm:"type:uuid;ForeignKey:ID;index"`
    ProjectID                      uuid.UUID `gorm:"type:uuid;index"`
    ChildModels                    []Model   `gorm:"ForeignKey:ParentModelID"`
}
```

And I need to select smth like this:

```
[{
  projectName: 'proj1',
  folderName: 'case1',
  models: [
    { id: 1 },  //no child
    { id: 2 },
    { id: 3, childFolderId: '12', childModelId: '12' },]
},
{
  projectName: 'proj1',
  folderName: 'case2',
  models: [
    { id: 4 },
    { id: 6, childFolderId: '23', childModelId: '23' }, },]
}], ...
```

So I need to get all models than belong to the same folder and get model child if there is one.
I am intrested if it is possible to get in one query. I dont have much experience with gorm and got this, but its not a full answer, but alows to get child models:

```
func preloadModel(db *gorm.DB) (dbFilter *gorm.DB) {
    filter = db.
      Preload("ChildModels", preloadModel).
      Select("models.*, ...").
      Joins("left join folders on folder.id = models.folder_id").
}
```